# Link to activate form field

Tags: html, forms

How can I make a form label activate (focus) the form field it coincides with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the `for` attribute on the label. It references the `id` attribute of the form input/field you want it to focus.

eg. `<input type="text" id="txt1" /><label for="txt1">Text 1</label>`